# HTML: How can I align this form?

Tags: html, forms

I have a form in my code, but it's off to the left side of the page. I don't know how to align it.

```
 <form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="5grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
      <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="12u">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="12u">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="12u">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message">
        <input type="reset" class="button button-alt" value="Clear Form">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And it looks like this :

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `form { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: You are using a bunch of `div`s. By default, they are block level elements. The way to remedy that is to either `float` them, or `display:inline-block` in your CSS of `.row`

Comment: Hmm... @mdesdev got me curious. Aligned how? Vertically, or horizontally?

Comment: @Oberst Horizontally...if that's the question ;)

Comment: @blutuu if this question has been answered could you please mark it as such. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want it horizontally centered, put your form inside a width-limited div parent, and a doc-wide div grandparent with centered content:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
 <div style="width: 400px; text-align: left;">
  <form ...
  ...
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

form {
width: 400px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
} 

</style>
 <form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="5grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
      <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="12u">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="12u">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="12u">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message">
        <input type="reset" class="button button-alt" value="Clear Form">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This should work